# Brownian martingale as time-space changed brownian

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $M$ be a true real martingale adapted to some brownian motion $B$.

What are the most generic conditions on $M$ to find a deterministic map $\Phi:\mathbb{R}_+\times\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_+\times \mathbb{R}$ with the following notation $\Phi(s,B_s)=(\Phi_1(s,B_s),\Phi_2(s,B_s))$ and such that 
$$ M_{\Phi_1(s,B_s)}=\Phi_2(s,B_s) $$

I feel the intuition that when $M$ is solution to nice SDE, it works, but could it be more generic ?

P.S : I know DDS theorem, and it does not answer to this question.

Comment: have you tried Itô on $\Phi_2(s,B_s)$ and Time Changed Itô on $M_{\Phi_1(s,B_s)}$ I think this article is treating the subject http://arxiv.org/pdf/0906.5385v2.pdf By identification then you might get your answer. Best regards